# Wrapper or inheritance for file parser in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, wrapper

I have a class that implements a parser for a specific file format.
I want to add a support for another format. It seems to me that this can be done in two ways:

**Option 1:** Implement several parser methods in the same class, check the file extension and call the appropriate method for processing:

```
class FileParser:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)[1]
        if self.ext == '.foo':
            self.data = self._parse_foo(file_name)
        elif self.ext == '.bar':
            self.data = self._parse_bar(file_name)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Wrong file extension')

    def _parse_foo(self,file_name):
        pass

    def _parse_bar(self,file_name):
        pass

    def do_great_things_with_data(self):
        pass
```

**Option 2:** Implement parsers for each file format in subclasses. Then make a object  factory to select subclass in accordance with the file extension:

```
class FileParser:
    @staticmethod
    def load_file(file_name):
        ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)[1]
        if ext == '.foo':
            return FooFileParser(file_name)
        elif ext == '.bar':
            return BarFileParser(file_name)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Wrong file extension')

     def do_great_things_with_data(self):
        pass

class FooFileParser(FileParser):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class BarFileParser(FileParser):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Which approach is better to use? What each have advantages / disadvantages?

Comment: Since both approaches are functionally valid, the only person that can really and truly answer that question is you. A non-opinion based version of this question would ask about the potential consequences of the differences between the approaches. But "better" can only be answered by you because it's how those consequences apply to your very particular situation.

Comment: I'd personnaly rather use two different classes (with our without inheritance, depending on how much common code they share) and a plain function as factory. But as Mad Physicists mentions, when two solutions are functionally equivalent, which one is "the best" is mainly a matter of context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there’s a third option: Define parse functions for each format at the module level. Is there an actual need to place them in a class?

A small example:

```
def parse_foo(f):
    pass

def parse_bar(f):
    pass

PARSERS = {
    ".foo": parse_foo,
    ".bar": parse_bar,
}

def load_file(parsers, name):
    try:
        parse = parsers[os.path.splitext(name)[-1]]
    except KeyError as e:
        raise RuntimeError("no parser for {}".format(e))
    with open(name) as f:
        return parse(f)

load_file(PARSERS, "myfile.foo")
```

Comment: I need class to embed data processing in it after parsing.

Comment: @Aleksei Joel's point is that you can separate the tasks of parsing the file and interpreting the data. If you do that, you can load any type of file into the format you interpret later, and the data interpreter doesn't care where the data came from as long as the structure in memory is correct.

Comment: And by the way I will not have partially defined objects if parser fails. That's a good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the filetype beforehand, then I suggest the first approach: you have one class that selects an appropiate internal method depending on the file extension.

- This would be useful if you have, for example, only one API endpoint where a user can upload any kind of file, but you use only one file parser class there which has to internally select the correct parsing method to use.

---

The second approach is only useful (in my opinion) if you know the filetype beforehand but don't want to repeat the code.

- For example, you have different API endpoints for each filetype; each endpoint would use its own subclass of the file parser and only override the part that is specific to that file extension.

Comment: With your first case, dispatching to the proper parser should be the API's responsabilty, not the parser's.

Comment: With the second option, registering child classes is a much more scalable way to select unknown types.